# Can't get my next form to open due to "Error creating Window Handle" error

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am using the same syntax I have always used to open my next form with a button click, however in this new program it keeps throwing 'Win32Exception was unhandled, Error creating window handle' when I click the button that runs my code to open the next form. The syntax for what I'm as it currently sets is as follows.

```
        startGuessing game = new startGuessing(min.Text, max.Text);//both variables being passed to next form for more interaction
        this.Hide();//hide current form
        game.ShowDialog();//opens startGuessing form - this line is where the error is thrown
```

I have no clue, why this isn't working here when it has worked so many times in the past. [MSDN Troubleshooting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(EHCWIN32);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2CVERSION%3DV4.0%22);k(DevLang-CSHARP)&rd=true) says something about NativeErrorCode property that I don't understand since I have never had to mess with it in the past. Any help in either why my code is all the suddenly not working or a better more understandable explanation of what the MSDN Troubleshooting is saying.

please and thank you.

Comment: sounds like the program is [running out of handle](http://www.stardock.com/screenshots/task2.jpg). Open Windows Task Manager, in the Processes tab, find the program and find out how many handles are being used by your program (the listview has a `Handles` column)

Comment: it still throws the error if I completely shut down, restart my computer, and re-launch the program

Comment: I just replicated the error in a new windows form that does absolutely nothing except open a new form and then closes the application on a button click. I checked my task manager and nothing in there even suggests that anything is reaching a predetermined limit. If I try to push the program past the above error then a new error appears - error title "InvalidOperationException was unhandled" the body of the error reads "Form that is already displayed modally cannot be displayed as a modal dialog box. Close the form before calling showDialog."

Comment: However using the exact same lines of code in my older programs and open multiple form on top of other forms, anywhere from 2 or 3 forms in or 30 forms in and they all open with no error at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to resolving my issue had nothing to do with what my errors were complaining about. The issue was caused by a line of code that I had forgotten to put into my second form, that I use to check for a click event on the control box red X. On the event of the click it closes my application no matter how far I am into my application as long as the code exists within the form.

Thank you to those of you that actually tried to help me :)